# Rewrite entire git history

Tags: git, github

Quite awhile back, I forked a repo on github and made quite a few changes to several unrelated features, and at the time I knew basically nothing about git, so my commits are basically just "whatever I happened to have worked on since whenever the last time I remembered to commit was".  I would like to contribute some of my changes upstream, but that isn't possible with my repo in its current state.  Now that I've actually been using git long enough to be comfortable with it, and more aware of good practices, is it possible to rewrite my entire commit history in order to break up the small number of large commits, each containing many unrelated changes, into smaller individual commits, only containing related changes?  If nothing else, I can just delete the fork on Github, re-fork, overwrite everything with my current local copies and run a bunch of partial commits, but if there's a better way that would be nice.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-rebase/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to rewrite the entire history... but for your case you don't have to. You just need to rewrite the bits you worked on. This is, probably, just the changes to your `master` branch. For that you can do an interactive rebase for all the changes between `master` and `origin/master` which is what they have upstream.

To do this, first checkout master and then `git rebase -i origin/master`. This will throw you into an editor where you can choose what to do with each commit. You probably want to edit them (`e`). Once you save the file Git will checkout each change in turn and you can do what you like with it.

If you want to split up a commit, use [`git add -p` and `git add -i`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging) to add the change a piece at a time to the staging area, then `git commit` to commit just that one part of the change.

For more detail, read [Rewriting History in Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) and Github's [About Git Rebase](https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-rebase/).

Comment: Oh, duh.  Thanks, I completely spaced on the fact that because it was a forked repo *my* history is not the same as the entire repo history.  You are correct that I only need to edit my own commits.  I've tried rebase a few times and have never quite figured it out, but I'll give it another look.

Answer (score 0):

Deeply modifying commit history with `git` is typically done with the `rebase` command. Git provides powerful tooling to manipulate git history however you want, but your question is too broad to really provide a useful answer:

> is it possible to rewrite my entire commit history?

Yes, you can.

But what exactly are you looking to do? People need an example and a specific problem that you need help with.

---

**One example option that creates a history where each file is added per commit:**

I assume your current HEAD is at `master` with the final desired state of code.

```
git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD | tail -1 # gets commits with no parents
```

should return the SHA of the very first commit. `checkout` that SHA.

```
git checkout $(git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD | tail -1)
git checkout -b rewritten-history
```

Now, for every file in your final desired state of code:

```
git checkout master -- <<filepath>> # gets file and adds to git index
git commit -m "Added <<filepath>>"
```

After you've done this, `master` and `rewritten-history` should be the same:

```
git diff rewritten-history master # should return no differences
```

And now you can move `master` to top of the new history:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard rewritten-history
git branch -d rewritten-history # optional, since you don't need this anymore
```

If you're thinking that this would take a lot of work, you're probably right. Like constantly/iteratively refactoring for consistent code quality, it's much easier to have kept git history clean than it is to go back and fix history after the fact.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my original question to clarify, but what I have is a small number of very large commits that contain a lot of unrelated changes, and what I need to do is break those up into smaller separate commits that each only contain related changes, so that those smaller commits can be used in a pull request.  Does that sufficiently answer your question?

Comment: That's certainly _doable_, but just as a warning it's quite involved. It's like asking "How do I drive to New York?" when you just learned how to use a car, don't know how to read road signs, and are unfamiliar with American traffic rules. I'll add a simple example of one option to my answer.